# arrayList not saving names?

Tags: java, bukkit

Im am creating a Plugin for Bukkit. But I need to store PlayerName's in an List, now I am using an ArrayList but it dont seem to save them?

Here's my code:

```
public class Menu implements Listener {
private static Menu instance = new Menu();

public static Menu getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

ArrayList<String> inMenu = new ArrayList<String>();

public void menuAdd(Player p) {
    if(inMenu.contains(p.getName())) {return;}
    inMenu.add(p.getName());
     [1]p.sendMessage(inMenu.toString());

}

@EventHandler
  public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
    [2]e.getPlayer().sendMessage(inMenu.toString());
    if(inMenu.contains(e.getPlayer().getName())) {
        if(e.getMessage().contains("appel")) {
            inMenu.remove(e.getPlayer().getName());
        }
        return;
    } else{
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage("Not in list");
    }

  }
```

At [1] it debugs that the playerName is in the ArrayList but when I debug it at [2] nothing is in the list?

Main:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

private static Main instance;
private static Plugin plugin;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
    pm.registerEvents(this, this);


        if(getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Citizens") == null || getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Citizens").isEnabled() == false) {
            System.out.print("Citizens 2.0 not found or not enabled");
            getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this); 
            return;
        }
        net.citizensnpcs.api.CitizensAPI.getTraitFactory().registerTrait(net.citizensnpcs.api.trait.TraitInfo.create(HorecaTrait.class).withName("Horeca"));

        instance = this;

        plugin = this;

        registerEvents(this, new Menu(), new HorecaTrait());
}
```

Comment: Show us code in which you are instancing Menu?

Comment: @Petar added the Main class

Comment: Show us more information? Where is call of the menuAdd method?

Answer (score 0):

You're using your `menu.getInstance()` method wrong.  You created a `new menu()` in your `onEnable()` method, but I am guessing (though there isn't proof of this) that you are using `Menu.getInstance().menuAdd()` to add it.  To fix it, change the `new menu()` in `onEnable()` to `Menu.getInstance()`.

Main class changed to work right:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    private static Main instance;
    private static Plugin plugin;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        pm.registerEvents(this, this);


        if(getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Citizens") == null || getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Citizens").isEnabled() == false) {
            System.out.print("Citizens 2.0 not found or not enabled");
            getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);    
            return;
        }
        net.citizensnpcs.api.CitizensAPI.getTraitFactory().registerTrait(net.citizensnpcs.api.trait.TraitInfo.create(HorecaTrait.class).withName("Horeca"));

        instance = this;

        plugin = this;

        registerEvents(this, Menu.getInstance(), new HorecaTrait()); //CHANGED HERE.
    }
```

As a side note, you probably don't need both `instance` and `plugin`, as your `Main` is actually also a `Plugin`.